# subject predicate complements and object predicate complements

Tags: syntax, parts-of-speech

Is there an easy way of determining which part of a sentence subject predicate complement (PCs) and which is a object predicate complement (PCo)?

my understanding is very surface level with complements - that complements follow copula verbs

For the example sentence:
"Joseph Lister introduced sterilisation to the world in the mid-19th century"

Predicates contain the main verb of a sentence - 'introduced'

Joseph Lister = subject

sterilisation = subject complement?? or is this the object..?

to the world = object complement??

in the mid-19thh century = adjunct?

But I'm also aware predicate complements can't be passivised but the example sentence can? -> "Sterilisation was introduced to the world by Joseph Lister in the mid-19th century."

My tentative conclusion is that:

Subject = joseph lister

predicate = introduced

object = sterilisation

to the world = PCo

in the mid-19th century = adjunct

Please correct me if i'm wrong!

Comment: Are you sure you can talk about subject complements if there is no _linking verb_ in the sentence? By “linking verbs” I mean "be," "seem," "appear," "become," "feel," "look," "smell," "sound," "taste," "stay," "grow," etc. [Have a look](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/subject-complement/). As for object complements, which _describe or rename the direct object of the verb_, they are also found in sentences with specific verbs like “call,” “consider,” “find,” “call,” “name“, etc., which is not the case with your sentence. [Have a look](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/object-complement/).

Comment: You say that “complements follow copular verbs” – this is true (though it’s actually linking verbs as Yellow Sky says, which is a broader category than copular verbs). But then you give an example which _doesn’t use a linking verb_, so why should it be followed by a complement?

Comment: I think I understand a little more - so subject complements follow linking verbs (which are verbs that must describe the subject) and they must be there to make the sentence grammatical. Regarding the verb introduced, would that make 'to the world' the object complement? (since it's describing 'sterilisation' which I assume is the DO). Finally, just confirming that this means 'introduced' is just called a transitive verb'?

Comment: Since it's not meant in the sentence that it's the world that's going to be sterilized, 'to the world' is not describing 'sterilisation', it about _introducing_ (to whom?) to the world.

Comment: so that would make 'to the world' the indirect object? As in 'she (s) gave the letter (DO) to them (IDO)'

Comment: @Amy The simple answer to your main question is that subjective PCs relate to the subject, while objective PCs relate to the object. In both cases, the PC is complement of the verb, not of the subj or obj. Note that the item they relate to is called the 'predicand'.

Comment: @Amy In your example "Joseph Lister introduced sterilisation to the world in the mid-19th century". the PP "to the world" is not indirect object of "introduced", though it does function as a non-core complement of the verb. Note that PPs don't function as indirect objects. Yes, the PP "in the mid-19th century" is a temporal adjunct in clause structure.